# The argument type 'InputDecoration' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'InputDecoration?'

Tags: flutter, dart

'm trying to make a simple  `TextField` with `InputDecoration` . and when I'm using `decoratoin:InputDecoration()`, It shows a problem . any idea why ??

```
class InputDecoration extends StatelessWidget {
  const InputDecoration({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext conyext) {
    return TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.grey.shade800,
        fontSize: 16.0,
      ),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Hint Text',
        errorText: 'Error Text',
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the error :

```
The argument type 'InputDecoration' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'InputDecoration?'.at  [190:19]

No branch
95
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We already have `InputDecoration`, rename your class

```dart
class MyInputDecoration extends StatelessWidget {
 const  MyInputDecoration({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext conyext) {
    return TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.grey.shade800,
        fontSize: 16.0,
      ),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Hint Text',
        errorText: 'Error Text',
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```